# Nested For loop not printing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nested-loops

I'm coding a nested for loop to fill a multidimensional array and have run into, not necessarily a problem, but a conundrum. First i'll explain that the code does what i want it to do which is fill a multi dimensional array completely with something; for now that something is the number 1. My conundrum comes when inside the for loop i have a "print()" function. To clear things up im coding c# inside unity.

```
static int[,] array;
array = new int[5,5];

for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
    print("outer: " + x);

    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
        print("-inner: " + y);
        array [x, y] = 1;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
outer: 0
-inner: 0
-inner: 1
-inner: 2
-inner: 3
-inner: 4
outer: 1
outer: 2
outer: 3
outer: 4
```

It won't print inner between ever outer yet when outside the for loop i directly try to print something like:

```
print("data: " + array[2,3]);
```

It outputs:

```
data: 1
```

So its clearly filling the array using the nested for loops but it isn't printing out my string every time it iterates within the nested for loop. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I replace `print` with `Console.WriteLine` (and remove `static` from the array definition and put all the code in `Main`). Can you please post a complete, minimal sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: If it is Unity instead of `print` try to use `Debug.Log()`

Comment: It's not that my code doesn't work. It does what it is created for. It fills a multidimensional array. What im having an issue with is why its able to fill the multidimensional array but yet it wont repeat the print function every iteration of y. This is only inside Unity. This is my conundrum.

Comment: Also derHugo, Debug.Log("test") also just runs once and never again every iteration.  (sorry for double post couldn't edit my message)

Answer (score 3):

It isn't about for loop or another coding thing! Just disable the "Collapse" option from your Unity editor's "Console" and it is OK.

[image: Here it is]

If you enable it, it will only print each unique message once with a counter on the right side indicating the number of times it printed.

Comment: Huh...i literally googled this for 5 hours and didn't ever find that as an answer. Never once would i have assumed collapse prevented it from showing how many times it printed. I assumed collapse simply collapsed all the duplicate errors and not everything. >.< Thanks.